# Getting screen width Android in dips

Tags: java, android, width, screen, density-independent-pixel

I want to get the screen width , and set it to my layout which is a child of a Horizontal Scroll View . I am doing this but it makes my layout wider than I want .

padding is defined with dips.

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

    float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;    
    int padding = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding); 
    layoutWidth = (int) ((outMetrics.widthPixels * density) - 2*padding);
```

Comment: if you want to add the view dynamically then why don't you use `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` ?

Comment: because the container layout in the HorizontalScrollView cant be match_parent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
 DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
 display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

 float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
 float dpHeight = outMetrics.heightPixels / density;
 float dpWidth  = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;
```

Also refer: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels

Comment: :( . It'l help if you can paste the xml and code where you set the layout width

Comment: I create the Layout with LayoutInflator , and this is where I set the width 
`container.getLayoutParams().width = width;`

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize following code of mine.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.mehuljoisar.d_screensize;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ScreenSizeUtils mScreenSizeUtils = new ScreenSizeUtils(MainActivity.this);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPx)).setText("wxh (px): "+mScreenSizeUtils.GET_widthxheight_px());
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDp)).setText("wxh (dp): "+mScreenSizeUtils.GET_widthxheight_dp());

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPx"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvPx" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ScreenSizeUtils.java**

```
package com.mehuljoisar.d_screensize;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class ScreenSizeUtils {

    // helper classes
    private Context mContext;
    private WindowManager mWm;
    private Display mDisplay;
    private Configuration mConfig;
    private DisplayMetrics mDisplayMetrics, mRealDisplayMetrics;

    // helper attributes
    private static final int Unknown = -255;

    private int width_px, height_px;
    private int width_dp, height_dp;


    //values
    private String widthxheight_px;
    private String widthxheight_dp;


    public ScreenSizeUtils(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mWm = ((WindowManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));
        mDisplay = mWm.getDefaultDisplay();
        mConfig = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration();
        mDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        mDisplay.getMetrics(mDisplayMetrics);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
        {
            mRealDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            mDisplay.getRealMetrics(mRealDisplayMetrics);
        }
    }

    public String GET_widthxheight_px() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 13) {
            width_px = mDisplay.getWidth();
            height_px = mDisplay.getHeight();
        } else {
            Point mPoint = new Point();
            mDisplay.getSize(mPoint);
            width_px = mPoint.x;
            height_px = mPoint.y;
        }
        widthxheight_px = width_px + " x " + height_px;
        return widthxheight_px;
    }

    public String GET_widthxheight_dp() {
        int real_width_px = Unknown;
        int real_height_px = Unknown;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            real_width_px = mRealDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;
            real_height_px = mRealDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;
        }
        else
        {
            //it is necessary if you haven't called it before
            GET_widthxheight_px();
        }

        height_dp = (int) (((double) ((real_height_px == Unknown) ? height_px
                : real_height_px) / mDisplayMetrics.density) + 0.5);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
            width_dp = mConfig.screenWidthDp;
        } else {
            width_dp = (int) (((double) ((real_width_px == Unknown) ? width_px
                    : real_width_px) / mDisplayMetrics.density) + 0.5);
        }

        widthxheight_dp = width_dp + " x " + height_dp;
        return widthxheight_dp;
    }

}
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screen-size demo]

I hope it will be helpful !!

Answer (score 0):

This code will return width (w) & height (h) of screen.

```
DisplayMetrics dMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dMetrics);
float density = dMetrics.density;
int w = Math.round(dMetrics.widthPixels / density);
int h = Math.round(dMetrics.heightPixels / density);
```

activity is instance of Activity which would you like to get screen size.

You have to remember that: When your device is in landscape orientation, w > h. When it in portrait orientation w < h.

So from width & height you can detect your device is in what orientation.

Comment: I have tried this , but it didn't help also. I am getting too wide Layout. I think `int w` doesn't contain the screen width in dips